# django pass extra option through url templatetag to view

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following line in my url file

```
url(r'^confirm/$', 'confirm', {'status':'live'}, name="confirm"),
```

As you can see I am passing the extra option `status` to the view which is described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions)

I would like to pass the status value through the template using the `url` templatetag.  I tried

`{% url confirm status='pending' %}` but I get the following error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'status': u'pending'}' not found.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How could this work? The `url` tag just outputs a URL that is valid in your urlconf and which maps the arguments into the URL. But your url has no place for alternative values for status - it's hard-coded.

If you want to pass parameters into a URL pattern, the pattern needs to have a space for the parameter.